# How to make a smooth kernel in Convolution Neural Networks with MXNet framework?

Tags: r, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, mxnet

My datasets is [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/), and ML library is [MXNet](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/)

I used the CNN algorithm to practice ML. Then I found the reference tutorial, [page 6 and 7](http://web.pdx.edu/~jduh/courses/Archive/geog481w07/Students/Ludwig_ImageConvolution.pdf).

[image: smoothly kernel]

I guess the default kernel is all '1' instances in a matrix (kernel in MXNet). How to make the smoothly kernel like above slide.

---

This is the MXNet code with R.

```
mx.symbol.Convolution(data=data, kernel=c(5,5), num_filter=20)
```

Comment: Please consider including the data and all the relevant code in your question to sever the ties to off-site resources that may go offline without notice.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you are trying to do image filtering using `MXNet`, you may be using the wrong tool.  There is a way to specify array initialization, but you will be changing the weights if you want to do any learning with backprop.  If you just want to convolve a kernel over an image, look at `spatialfil` or `imager` packages.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, MXNet is a framework for deep-learning. The slides that you referenced are image processing tasks that have other optimized tools, [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) being one of the most popular ones. Nevertheless, you can perform simple convolution using MXNet as well. In python, it would look like this:

```
# Replace img with an actual image
img = np.random.uniform(size=(1, 1, 480, 640))
img = mx.nd.array(img)
w = mx.nd.array([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 5, -1], [0, -1, 0]])
w.reshape((1, 1, 3, 3))
out = mx.nd.Convolution(
    img, w, kernel=(3, 3), num_filter=1, no_bias=True, pad=(1, 1))
```